# declaring an object with parenthesis and no arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

suppose I have a class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class namedType {
public:
    explicit namedType(const char* name, const T& ty):name(name), ty(ty){};
    explicit  namedType(const string &name, T ty) : name(name), ty(ty) {}
    friend ostream&operator<<(ostream& ostr, namedType& nm){
        cout<<nm.name<<" , "<<nm.ty<<endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
    T ty;
};
```

I wonder why following code gets compiled and why the output is "1" ?

```
 namedType<float> nf(); // this is not right, but I do not know why !
 cout<<nf;
```

Comment: It's a function declaration, like `int foo();`.

Comment: In my case it compiles, but does not linkes. "Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class namedType<float> __cdecl nf(void)" (?nf@@YA?AV?$namedType@M@@XZ) referenced in function _main"

Comment: Provide please full sample. I do not believe that you get such a strange result)

Comment: @DmytroDadyka - Believe it. There's UB and weirdness involved.

Comment: `namedType<float> nf();` is a function declaration, so `cout<<nf;` would be equivalent to `cout << bool(&nf);` (not-nullity of address of function pointer) (so true) (from all overloads "`cout << bool(b)`" is the best viable candidate).

Comment: @Jarod42 many thanks, your explanation clarified it for me